# Why does Windows phone 7 UDP receiving fail?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, udp

I have one multicast project from "[Peer Communication on Windows Phone 7](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/217754/Peer-Communication-on-Windows-Phone-7)".

I am using a Samsung GT-18350 phone for testing.

The working Windows Phone Version:

- OS Version: 7.10.7740.16
- Firmware revision number:2424.11.11.7
- Hardware revision number:23.15.0.8
- Radio Software version:0424.11.11.7
- Radio hardware version:0.0.0.800
- Bootloader version:5.11.17.0
- Chip SOC version:0.74.2.1

I am tested that application with this Samsung mobile with the above configuration. It's working fine, but after updating of the configuration below it's not working.

Not working in the latest version of Windows Phone 7:

- OS Version: 7.10.8107.79
- Firmware revision number:2424.12.01.1
- Hardware revision number:23.15.0.8
- Radio Software version:0424.12.1.1
- Radio hardware version:0.0.0.800
- Bootloader version:6.1.2.0
- Chip SOC version:0.74.2.1

How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: -1 Helps if you tell us what the issue is.

Comment: Can you post details of the error, particularly the line of code this is failing on?  Do you know if there are any available release notes for the upgrade?  It might be worth noting that the project on Code Project appears to have been written against a pre-release version, so they might have deprecated some existing functionality in this upgrade.

Comment: There is no error shown,before Version (OS Version: 7.10.7740.16),it sending and receiving message from Samsung GT-18350 phone to phone emulator, but after updated the (OS Version 7.10.8107.79) its not receiving message, but it sending the message from phone to phone,but not receiving any message from any device, and not shown any error too